# How to write a case statement showing null to a value and vice versa Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have a table like

| ID | COUNTRY_1 | COUNTRY_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | USA | CAN |
| 6 | NULL | USA |
| 7 | MEX | NULL |

I am writing a query such that I can show what the values change to within a singular column. For example I am trying to create a table like

| ID | CHANGES |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | USA `->` CAN |
| 6 | NULL `->` USA |
| 7 | MEX `->` NULL |

I wrote my query like

```
    SELECT ID, CASE WHEN COUNTRY_1 <> COUNTRY_2 THEN COUNTRY_1 || '->' || COUNTRY_2 ELSE '' END   
    AS CHANGES FROM MY_TABLE
```

However this resulted in a table like

| ID | CHANGES |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | USA `->` CAN |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |

which doesnt show a change from a value to NULL or NULL to a value, is there a way I can show these changes as well in my tables in addition to a non-null value to another non-null value? Thanks!

Comment: NULL is not a string, which is why you are having the issue you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert nulls to 'NULL' then apply your query :

```
WITH CTE as (
   SELECT ID, CASE WHEN COUNTRY_1 IS NOT NULL THEN COUNTRY_1 ELSE 'NULL' END AS COUNTRY_1,
              CASE WHEN COUNTRY_2 IS NOT NULL THEN COUNTRY_2 ELSE 'NULL' END AS COUNTRY_2
   FROM MY_TABLE
   
)
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN COUNTRY_1 <> COUNTRY_2 
                THEN COUNTRY_1 || '->' || COUNTRY_2 
                ELSE '' END  AS CHANGES 
FROM CTE;
```